# Unable to locate Xpath Element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom, xpath

Hi I am fairly new to selenium .Can somebody please suggest on how to locate and element inside iframe asi am getting error below.

I am trying to implement an Automation Script on Salesforce Pardot page and there are 2 iframes and i want to access Button on 1st iframe Tag and click on same.

> **Error:-** selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[starts-with(@class,'slds-button_reset')]"}
>   (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.122)

[Screenshot for DOM Button Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42LVI.png)

[Screenshot for DOM Button Element along with Iframe tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XmSc.png)

**Code Written Previously**

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory': r'C:\Pardot'}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\XXX XXXX\XXXX\drivers\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://pi.pardot.com/engagementStudio/studio#/15627/reporting')
user_name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#email_address')
user_name.send_keys('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#password')
password.send_keys('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.btn')
submit_button.click()
iframe_list =  driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_list[0])
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@class,'slds-button_reset')]")
driver.close()
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried so far.

Comment: @Vipul_21 I am reverting back the changes for this time. If your requirement have changed, feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement. Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so to invoke `click()` on the element you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()`.
- You can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#content-frame")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-qa='reporting-filter-trigger-toggle'][data-ember-action]"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='content-frame']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-qa='reporting-filter-trigger-toggle' and @data-ember-action]"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)
- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Hi @Debanjan B thanks for your response, Button got clicked but I need to change value of span element to This Month.I have tried adding below line of code but no luck.

`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value(text_='This Month',locator=(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span[data-qa='reporting-filter-trigger-value']")))`

Comment: **for SS from DOM element along with dropdown List appear on clicking button**
Please refer to Question Post Above I have added Just now.

Comment: @Vipul_21 That should be a separate question altogether. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement please?

Comment: can you Pls check on this post as I have posted separate Question for the same.  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60501908/how-to-access-span-element-under-a-dropdown-list-w-r-t-python-selenium-script

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
//li[@id='ember943']

Comment: It will throw Error as locator could not able to locate Xpath Element--> //li[@id='ember943']

Answer (score 0):

You need to get iframe tag first and switch driver to it like following.

`driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))`
assuming that driver is a healthy instance of webdriver. To continue with the default content do 
`driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Please refer [this link](https://www.techbeamers.com/switch-between-iframes-selenium-python/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you're switching to the correct Iframe to fetch the element... Please see the example below

```
driver.switchTo().frame("content-frame")
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ember740']/div[2]/div/ol/li/div/button")
driver.switchTo().defaultContent()
```

Comment: Getting Error Str object is Not callable.